# OSError: file does not exist using ytree

Tags: python, oserror

I've got some data I need to load using ytree which can be done via:

```
import ytree

a = ytree.load('ctrees.h5')
```

However, doing this gives the following error:

```
OSError: file does not exist: ctrees.h5.
```

With traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "C:\Users\Documents\untitled1.py", line 3, in <module>
a = ytree.load('ctrees.h5')

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ytree\data_structures\arbor.py", line 1089, in load
raise IOError("file does not exist: %s." % filename)

OSError: file does not exist: ctrees.h5.
```

The same happens if I try a = ytree.load("ctrees.h5"). I can see that the file exists, I have changed the working directory to the correct one and my script is saved in the same directory. I also tried specifying the full path to the file with no joy.
I'm using Python 3.7 and ytree 2.3 on Windows 10

Any help appreciated.

EDIT (RESOLVED):
Fixed the issue by specifying path at top of script and reading file as:

```
PATH='C:\\path\\to\\file\\directory\\'

a = ytree.load(PATH + "ctrees.h5")
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a hidden file extension on the file? In folder options you should be able to show hidden file extensions or something like that.

Comment: Not that I could find